# Issue with [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] in credentials provider

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I am having an issue with nextjs auth that it shows

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error undefined {
  error: {},
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session',
  message: undefined
}
```

whenever i get session or user from that, pls help.

My code:

1. [...nextauth].js

```js
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import User from '../../../models/User';
import db from '../../../utils/db';

export default NextAuth({
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user?._id) token._id = user._id;
      if (user?.isAdmin) token.isAdmin = user.isAdmin;
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token?._id) session.user._id = token._id;
      if (token?.isAdmin) session.user.isAdmin = token.isAdmin;
      return session;
    },
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        await db.connect();
        const user = await User.findOne({
          email: credentials.email,
        });
        await db.disconnect();
        if (user && bcryptjs.compareSync(credentials.password, user.password)) {
          return {
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            image: 'f',
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
          };
        }
        throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

2. Api (update-profile.js)

```js
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs';
import User from '../../../models/User';
import db from '../../../utils/db';

async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'PUT') {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: `${req.method} not supported` });
  }

  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (!session) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'signin required' });
  }

  const { user } = session;
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  if (
    !name ||
    !email ||
    !email.includes('@') ||
    (password && password.trim().length < 5)
  ) {
    res.status(422).json({
      message: 'Validation error',
    });
    return;
  }

  await db.connect();
  const toUpdateUser = await User.findById(user._id);
  toUpdateUser.name = name;
  toUpdateUser.email = email;

  if (password) {
    toUpdateUser.password = bcryptjs.hashSync(password);
  }

  await toUpdateUser.save();
  await db.disconnect();
  res.send({
    message: 'User updated',
  });
}

export default handler;
```

3} Main page (profile.js)

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { getError } from '../utils/error';
import axios from 'axios';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default function ProfileScreen() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue('name', session.user.name);
    setValue('email', session.user.email);
  }, [session.user, setValue]);

  const submitHandler = async ({ name, email, password }) => {
    try {
      await axios.put('/api/auth/update', {
        name,
        email,
        password,
      });
      const result = await signIn('credentials', {
        redirect: false,
        email,
        password,
      });
      toast.success('Profile updated successfully');
      if (result.error) {
        toast.error(result.error);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(getError(err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Layout title="Profile">
      <form
        className="mx-auto max-w-screen-md"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}
      >
        <h1 className="mb-4 text-xl">Update Profile</h1>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="w-full"
            id="name"
            autoFocus
            {...register('name', {
              required: 'Please enter name',
            })}
          />
          {errors.name && (
            <div className="text-red-500">{errors.name.message}</div>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="w-full"
            id="email"
            {...register('email', {
              required: 'Please enter email',
              pattern: {
                value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/i,
                message: 'Please enter valid email',
              },
            })}
          />
          {errors.email && (
            <div className="text-red-500">{errors.email.message}</div>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            className="w-full"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            {...register('password', {
              minLength: { value: 6, message: 'password is more than 5 chars' },
            })}
          />
          {errors.password && (
            <div className="text-red-500 ">{errors.password.message}</div>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
          <input
            className="w-full"
            type="password"
            id="confirmPassword"
            {...register('confirmPassword', {
              validate: (value) => value === getValues('password'),
              minLength: {
                value: 6,
                message: 'confirm password is more than 5 chars',
              },
            })}
          />
          {errors.confirmPassword && (
            <div className="text-red-500 ">
              {errors.confirmPassword.message}
            </div>
          )}
          {errors.confirmPassword &&
            errors.confirmPassword.type === 'validate' && (
              <div className="text-red-500 ">Password do not match</div>
            )}
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <button className="primary-button">Update Profile</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  );
}

ProfileScreen.auth = true;
```

***I am a beginner and i cannot understand the concept of nextauth and i am using next js version 13.2.0 and next auth version 4.3.4***